# How does Raspbian Jessie set the hostname during system startup?

Tags: boot, init.d, systemd

Most systems seem to read the contents of `/etc/hostname` and make a call to `/bin/hostname` during the system startup from an init.d (or similar) script.

Raspbian Jessie appears to have a different way to do this. I've modified the `/etc/hostname` file to a new name, and I've renamed `/bin/hostname` to `/bin/bup`.hostname so that any init scripts will not be able to find it. But the system boots up and uses the new host name, confirmed by running `/bin/bup.hostname`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian Jessie uses systemd which reads the /etc/hostname and sets the hostname directly with a system call. See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostname.html

systemd does not use /bin/hostname to set the hostname.